# GCP - Enabling External Identity Provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity, identity-aware-proxy

Trying to add external provider (github) to authenticate user. However, I am running in to following error during Google Cloud Identity Platform setting

> There was an error in updating the GCIP settings. You can return to
> your configuration and retry later

Create Cloud Run Instance step is successful.
Add Authorized Domain step is failure

It looks like server is responding with 400 status code for PATCH request

```
Request URL: https://iap.clients6.google.com/v1/projects/<project id>/iap_web/appengine-test-3-295108123:iapSettings?updateMask=iapSettings.accessSettings.gcipSettings.tenantIds,iapSettings.accessSettings.gcipSettings.loginPageUri&key=<apikey masked>
Request Method: PATCH
Status Code: 400
```

**UPDATE**
Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) is enabled on App Engine to protect static artifacts deployed on app engine (python runtime)

Comment: provide more information about your infrastructure. Do you have an identity-aware proxy somewhere?

Comment: @NeatNerd Yes. I do have IAP. I have frontend apps javascript artifacts deployed on app engine using python 3 runtime. I would like to protect the static resources using external providers and hence added GCIP (github) provider.

Comment: This issue is being investigated in this [issue tracker thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/173134426)

Comment: @hbmuser Did you found any solution to this? I have a similar issue while enabling the external identity in Google cloud IAP. I have followed all of the steps mention in ( https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enable-external-identities ) but could not be able to enable external identity and got the following error message:

"Failed to update settings for external identity"